# WebRTC: share media between two client in some network

Tags: javascript, webrtc

i have a very basic question.
with WebRTC, i want to send/receive data and share media between two clients in some network.
(like 192.168.2.10 and 192.168.2.20)
i know that in public network, we need server to connecting clients;
but all example's without server parameter that i seen, both sender and receiver in some page. i want to know, is this possible to share media with WebRTC between two clients in some network, without server? if yes, how?

Comment: not using WebRTC there is not, you will still have to use a signalling method to exchange their generated SDPs...

Comment: yes, you have to use *something* to exchange the SDPs and possibly the candidates. Copy/paste, e-mail, server, whatever you want, but someone, somehow needs to do it (note that the candidates are usually only valid for 30mn).